I am having trouble importing seaborn library in Jupyter Notebook. I have already installed matplotlib , NumPy and pandas
import seaborn as sns
After this , I got this error. The error message.
I tried restarting the kernel , but the issue is still not solved.
I tried installing 'seaborn' using the 'pip install seaborn' command in PowerShell. I made sure that I have matplotlib , NumPy and pandas installed. I restarted the kernel again. I installed openpyxl using the pip command. The issue is still not solved.

What do you mean by "I tried installing 'seaborn' using the 'pip install seaborn'"? you got an error message? did you install seaborn in the same env as the one you use in jupyter?

In your running notebook .ipynb file, add a cell and run the following: %pip install seaborn. The symbol at the start and where you run it is important. The % means use the magic variation of the install command that insures it installs to the proper environment where the kernel underlying the active notebook is running.If you are instead using Anaconda/conda, it would be %conda install conda-forge::seaborn based on use of the magic install command and command here. See more about the magic install commands that were added in 2019 to allow...

 better running of install commands inside running Jupyter Notebook files  here. Depending on how complex your system install of Jupyter is you may want to treat this as only a way to get past this hurdle. You may be better off sorting out where and how you should be installing things from the command line to give yourself more options in the long run. Installing from inside the notebook though good to have as an option in your toolbox.

Minor stuff: You should not be posting images/screenshots of errors. Paste in the entire error as text as described under 'Help others reproduce the problem' in the very useful guide How do I ask a good question?. See about 'fenced code blocks' here that you should be using to share code and error text as actually text that is searcheable and indexable by those trying to help you, and perhaps future you trying to find where you got helped in the past, and StackOveflow's system. Finally, similar ...

 questions like this are common on StackOverflow and you should endeavor to search out help and only post a new topic when you are sure your problem is different and new. Then you'd describe how your problem is different from the other ones in your post. See under 'Search, and research' in guide How do I ask a good question?. Note you may need to think more generally to find good help. For example, leave out the package name when searching the error to find things like ...

 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' on Jupyter Notebooks'.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
